# Select "COUNT" from a "GROUP BY"

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need help with this problem.

Having this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(30),
    Salary Money,
    BossId int,
    Ocupation varchar(20))

INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(1,'Juan',15000,7,'Ventas')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(2,'Federico',16000,7,'Ventas')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(3,'Marcos',12000,8,'Compras')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(4,'Alberto',9000,8,'Compras')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(5,'Gonzalo',5000,8,'Compras')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(6,'Noelia',13000,7,'Ventas')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(7,'Roberto',20000,9,'Ventas')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(8,'Diego',19000,9,'Ventas')
INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(9,'Damian',25000,null,'Compras')
```

How can I get the name, salary and number of employees in charge, of employees who are heads of more than two employees?

The result will be:

```
Roberto  2000   3 
Diego    19000  3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can the "depth" of the boss relationship be more than one?  IE can A be the boss of B who is the boss of C and D?

Comment: Yes, anyone can be boss of anyone. IE "Damian" is boss of "Diego" who is boss of "Gonzalo", "Alberto" and "Marcos".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    E1.Name
    , E1.Salary
    , COUNT(*) Employees
FROM
    Employees E1
    JOIN Employees E2 ON E1.Id = E2.BossId
GROUP BY
    E1.Name
    , E1.Salary
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: This actually would not work per @GianneBoschetto's previous comment.  Suppose  If A is allowed to be the boss of B who is the boss of C and D, this script would incorrectly return B, where the correct answer is A and B.

Comment: No sorry! I had not understood your question. Anyone can be the boss of anyone. But the problem question it's about the "direct" bosses. This works fine with my problem.

Comment: @DerekBrown My script would not incorrectly return B, as it is not recursive or anything like that; it simply returns the number of direct employees. B would only by in the BossId column twice, thus COUNT(*) would be 2, and the row for B would not return. Thanks.